# Evidence that requiring registration using facebook/twitter/google on a public terminal increases abandonment rates?

Tags: registration, facebook-connect, openid

I am working on a registration application which would be used in a live "museum" type experience.  Essentially, to enter the museum you need to register for a personal account to receive a ticket.

I am considering tapping Facebook/Twitter/Google APIs to decrease the total registration time per user by pulling their information through the respective API.  I can find information relating to using the APIs for website registration however my question is related to abandon rates when offering this on a public terminal.

Does anyone have non-anecdotal evidence which supports or denies increased abandonment rate on public (non-personal) devices when requiring Facebook, etc account information?

Comment: There is plenty of evidence that registration increases abandonment when done in private.  Considering the disadvantages of a public terminal (inherently harder to use an unfamiliar system, public systems are less secure, more people are looking over your shoulder, etc.), why do you believe public users would be **more** willing to register in public than in private, where it is already known that registration represents a barrier?

Comment: The ticket itself could be used as ID. Then users could use it to register at home after visiting a museum. So maybe you could change the flow, it is unclear from your post.

Comment: is it a UX related question?? i am new to here can anybody please tell me what is the purpose of this site.

Comment: @viewPagerSpecialist please see [about] and [help] pages and the [meta] site for any questions you have about the site!

Comment: @norabora Oh i didn't know that when they added about and help center before it was not there anyway thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Brian, where is the evidence?

Comment: @JamesJenkins: Just Google "shopping cart registration increases abandonment" (sans quotes).  Support for this claim is ubiquitous.  One of the most well known examples is probably [The $300 million button](http://www.uie.com/articles/three_hund_million_button/).

Comment: @Brian, your comments are becoming an answer with references.  Maybe you should post it?

Comment: @JamesJenkins: The OP specifically asked for real evidence that public devices should avoid asking for registration.  Unfortunately, I don't have any such evidence.  It's possible that UX experts came to the same conclusions I did and saw no need for a study specific to public venues.  More likely, I just am unaware of such studies.

Comment: So... only people with Facebook, Twitter, or G+ accounts - and those who want to register with their personal information - can get into the museum?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid I don't have a definite answer but **the only way to find out can be by doing some testing and finding out if users are willing to use Twitter\Facebook\Google login credentials**. The two user research studies I found show that many users may not be willing to use those login options if an existing login already exists.

To quote this [article from mail chimp](http://blog.mailchimp.com/social-login-buttons-arent-worth-it/)

> I did a little extra analytics footwork to see just how many people
>   were clicking the social login buttons. I was shocked to see that just
>   3.4% of the people that visited the login page actually used Facebook or Twitter to log in.

Similarly this [study by typepad](http://blog.leahculver.com/2009/11/log-in-or-sign-up-with-openid.html) has similar results and shows that most users prefer to use the type pads login option as opposed to other open authentication options. To quote the article

> To find out which services people are using to log in, I contacted
>   Jonathan March, Six Apart's Data Architect. I found out that while we
>   don't track every log in specifically, we can get a very rough
>   estimate by looking for a URL in a user's ID. Though the data is a bit
>   out of date, I think it is still very useful.
>
> [image]

That said, **this data is based upon the fact that users already have a login and people might not be willing to try a new login option even though its a social login**. To continue with the study, **the study states that surprisingly most of of the new logins came via open authentication.** To quote the article

> **What about sign up?**
>
> The previous graphs are based on data about users who have LOGGED IN
>   in the past few months. What about new users - users who have SIGNED
>   UP recently? Luckily Jonathan thought of this and followed up with
>   data and graphs on the growth of alternative authentication providers.
>   The results are a bit shocking.
>
> **User sign ups between 2 and 3 months ago (June 28 to July 28)**
>
> [image]
>
> **User sign ups between 1 and 2 months ago (July 28 to Aug 28)**
>
> [image]
>
> **User sign ups in the past month (Aug 28 to Sept 28)**
>
> [image]
>
> **OpenID user sign ups by provider by week**
>
> [image]

That said, I recommend reading [this article about which open authorization option](http://techcrunch.com/2013/04/08/report-46-of-social-login-users-still-choose-facebook-but-google-is-quickly-gaining-ground/) to choose if you decide to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

Like others, I do not have hard data for you. But I run several online services, and requiring registration is absolutely a barrier. If you are going to require registration, allow users to use an existing login (e.g., fb, twitter or g+), and don't ask for that login until the end of a demo period.

Comment: Welcome to UX.SE! Check out the [help] and [about] pages to learn more about getting the most out of this community! OP specifically asked for non-anecdotal evidence, which your answer does not provide so it's not really an answer to their question.